# Preview tag activity on target site during migration

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

Sometimes it is hard to determine which site a particular OT question should go.

---

[image]

---

One of the ways I make a decision is to open up each candidate site and look at the popularity of a post's tags on the target site.  This, as you may imagine, is a pain in the ar?s[se].

- ctrl-click both site links on the dialog
- on each tab, click the Tags link
- for each tab

  - for each tag
  - search for tag
  - compare followers, question count

I think the addition of a popup that displays the tag information on each site within the dialog could make this process much smoother and help make better migrations.  I'd suggest the popup show when hovering over each site's <tr>.

---

[image]

Comment: This would be clearer with narwhals...

Comment: 'tis true what JNK says. Where is he?

Comment: @jnk hell, I didn't want to spend too much time on it.  It was either narwhals or the prototype.  I don't have photoshop, ya know.  See, now you made me feel bad.  Damnit.  (whoops, sorry Lance)

Comment: Aw, hell, I just realized my regex matches "arss".

Answer (score 2):

It *could* be argued that on-topicness is not necessarily decided by the activity on the target site. Still, I like it.

Maybe the view could be a bit more condensed - like showing the tag name and number of followers directly in the dialog, as opposed to showing the entire tag popup? It would be a good indicator for a quick decision.

Comment: That'd be fine, too.  It is a prototype, ya know.  Perhaps the tags (as they are merged) on the target site can be listed below each, along with the number of questions with that tag and the number of followers.  Or, hell, you could come up with a simple algorithm that uses these numbers to create a "suitability index"...